# Unitary operators preserve the inner product between the vectors they act on.

Tags: notation, hilbert-spaces, physics, inner-products

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $U$ a unitary operator on $H$, that is, $U^\ast U=UU^\ast =I$ where $U^*$ denotes the adjoint of $U$. Then it is immediately clear that for $f,g\in H$ we have
$$
\langle Uf,Ug\rangle = \langle f,U^*Ug\rangle = \langle f,g\rangle.
$$
However in the physics text I am reading, the proof is as follows:

> Let $\vert V_1'\rangle=U\vert V_1\rangle$ and $\vert V_2'\rangle=U\vert V_2\rangle$ be kets. Then 
>   $$
> \langle V_2'\vert V_1'\rangle = \langle UV_2\vert UV_1\rangle = \langle V_2\vert U^*U\vert V_1\rangle = \langle V_2\vert V_1\rangle.
> $$

I am confused by this notation. Wouldn't $\langle V_2'\vert V_1'\rangle$ denote a $(\mathrm{bra}, \mathrm{ket})$ pair? Or in this case is it simply the inner product of $V_2'$ with $V_1'$? Moreover, what is the meaning of $\langle V_2\vert U^*U\vert V_1\rangle$? I get that of course $U^*U=I$ but the double $\langle\cdot\vert\cdot\vert\cdot\rangle$ notation is throwing me off.

Another example of the double $\vert$ notation:

> $\delta_{ij} = \langle i\vert U^*U\vert j\rangle$,

where $\delta_{ij} = \mathsf 1_{\{i=j\}}(i,j)$ is the Kronecker delta. What is the meaning of $\langle i\vert U^*U\vert j\rangle$?

Comment: Note: I am posting this here instead of https://physics.stackexchange.com because fundamentally this is a question about mathematical notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the bra-ket notation, $\langle x | y\rangle$ means the scalar product $\langle x,y\rangle$ of $x$ and $y$, and $\langle x | A| y\rangle$ means the scalar product $\langle x,Ay\rangle$ (here it's convenient to use the convention that the scalar product is linear in the second and antilinear in the first variable). Thus, the meaning of $\langle V_2|U^*U|V_1\rangle$ is just $\langle V_2,U^*UV_1\rangle$ which is equal to $\langle V_2,V_1\rangle$ as $U^*U=\operatorname{id}$.

Comment: But I thought a bra-ket $\langle\varphi\vert\psi\rangle$ meant that $\langle \varphi\vert = f_\varphi$ denoted an element in the dual space, by $f_\varphi(\psi) = \langle\varphi\vert\psi\rangle$ for $\psi\in H$.

Comment: This is an equivalent definition: by the Riesz representation theorem there is a canonical *antilinear* isomorphism between the dual space of a Hilbert space and the Hilbert space itself.

Comment: Ah yes, of course. Thank you.